# xml processing in worklight adapter

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, serverside-javascript

When we process XML in client side, we can use jQuery like:

```
var kids = jQuery("<a><kid>ABC</kid><kid>BCD</kid></a>").find("kid");
```

, now in adapter implementation script (i.e. MyAdapter-impl.js), can we have a similar solution to iterate over XML text or extract/update DOM nodes simply?
, currently I use Java function to do it, I'm looking for JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XSL Transformation to pre-process your XML before it is returning to the client.
Example can be found in these question:

- [What is the way to parse XML in a Worklight Adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350362/what-is-the-way-to-parse-xml-in-a-worklight-adapter)
- [how to perform xslt transformation for input request in adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973751/how-to-perform-xslt-transformation-for-input-request-in-adapter)

Alternatively, you can manipulate the JSON object in the adapter before `return`ing it.

Comment: With XSL transformation, the return type will be JSON style? I want my client app still get an XML text and process them strictly (Using JSON  my JavaScript will be cater for types of all JavaScript objects, i.e. when a tag repeated only 1 time and 2+ times, the JSON process give me different object graph, this takes too many debugging efforts).

Comment: The returned data is always a JSON object: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/server-side-development/adapter-framework-overview/